# Use Deep Links instead of Intent Navigation

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink, android-deep-link

I read a blog post that deep links can be used to replace the normal Intent navigation in the android app.

Is this method efficient ie does using deep links pose any significant overhead?

Does deep links pose any problem to the normal working of the app in some circumstances like no Internet etc?